# method for global existance for the NLS

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, schrodinger-operators

We consider the nonlinar Schr\"odinger equation(NLS): 
$$i\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\Delta_{x}u +\lambda |u|^{2k}u =0,  \ u(x, 0)= u_{0}(x);$$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb R, \  k \in \mathbb N,$ and  $u(x, t)$ is a complex valued function on $\mathbb R^{n} \times \mathbb R.$ By Duhamel's principle the integral version of  NLS has the form
$$u(\cdot, t)=e^{it \bigtriangleup}u_{0}(\cdot) -i\int_{0}^{t}e^{i(t-s)\Delta}(\lambda |u|^{2k}u)(s) ds.$$

Let $X$  be a Banach space (consists of functions/distributions on $\mathbb R^n$), and  for $T>0,$ we put $C([0, T], X)= \{f:[0, T]\to X: f \  \text{is continuous} \}.$

Assume that the above NLS has a unique local solution  $u \in C([0, T], X),$ for small $T>0.$

I am willing to understand the general philosophy for the global existence.

> **My Question is**:  What I need to prove(method) to show that the solution is global in time: $u\in C(\mathbb R, X)$?

[The paper I have been trying to understand claims that to show solution exists global in time it suffices to prove that Banch space norm  $\|u\|_{X}$ cannot become unbounded in finite time. But I do not understand how dose it follows from this. Would you please explain a bit?]

[ I am trying to understand Theorem 1.1 (page no.2  and then the proof in page no. 5) in of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.3615.pdf)].

Comment: A few comments: (1) in the paper you linked to global existence is assured in $L^2$ already; the paper itself claims that it is more of a propagation of regularity result. (2) do you know how to prove the analogue for _ordinary_ differential equations? Namely that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally Lipschitz then bounded solutions to $\dot{v} = f(v)$ exist for all time? The basic ideas are similar. [If you don't, this is covered in the first few pages of Hormander's Lectures on Nonlinear Hyperbolic Differential Equations, among other places.] (3) $X$ is not just any old Banach...

Comment: ...space in your linked paper. A general strategy requires choosing $X$ so that the analogue of $f$ that appears in the ODE case has the right properties to make it look like it is locally Lipschitz. (The mapping $u \mapsto |u|^p u$ for example in generally is not even well defined as a mapping from $L^q \to L^q$, except when $q = \infty$. It helps in the paper you linked to that the authors consider a Wiener algebra.)

Comment: @WW; Thanks, but I could not follow you. Kindly advise me on the following.  Yes, If understood correctly, the conservation law  $\|u(t)\|_{L^2}= \|u_0\|_{L^2}$ has been used to ensure the  $\|u\|_{W}$ cannot become unbounded in finite time. ($X$ is Wiener algebra) Up to this it is clear to me. After this I don't understand how does  $u\in C(\mathbb R, W)$ follows. [Please also tell me little about  propagation of regularity result; how does it help here?]

Comment: (1) The result you cited PROVES propagation of regularity. It does not use it. (2) Roughly $\| u(t_2)\|_W - \|u(t_1)\|_W \leq \| \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \partial_t u(s) ds \|_W$. Replace $\partial_t u$ using the equation, commute the $t$ integral with the norm in $W$, do some estimates, and get $\lesssim |t_2 - t_1| F(\|u\|_{L^\infty(t, W)})$. for some increasing function $F$.

Comment: Ack, I meant $\|u(t_2) - u(t_1)\|_W \leq\ldots$ not the difference of norms.

Comment: Most of the computation of the "do some estimates" part carries through exactly like in the proof of Prop 3.3 of the paper you linked to.

Comment: @WW;Set $w(t)=\sup_{0\leq \tau \leq T} \|u(\tau)\|_{W} (T>0).$ The Gronwall lemma shows that $w\in L^{\infty}([0, T]).$ This clear to me. The next arguments I don't follow: Since $T>0$ is arbitrary, $w\in L_{loc}^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ (How?) (I think, $T>0$ comes from local existence, using contraction method, how it can be arbitrary?)

Are you suggesting me to use some persistence of regularity arguments? Would you please advise me If I am missing something?

Comment: Your initial data is in $L^2\cap W$. So you can **already use the global existence result for $L^2$** to conclude that there is a solution in $L^2$. What you need to show is that this solution is in fact in the subspace $L^2 \cap W$. So you just need to be able to control the $W$ norm of the solution at a given time slice by the $W$ norm of the initial data. $T$ is emphatically NOT from the local existence, and is indeed arbitrary.

Comment: $WW; Thanks a lot. This is quite helpful.